# EXTJS Version 5.0, Chrome Latest (57): the top bar becomes invisible if grid has a title

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs, browser

Has anyone experienced the following issue->
Extjs : 5.0
Chrome: 57 (latest)

If a grid has a title, the top bat (tbar) of the grid becomes invisible along with grid headers. I can trace the elements in "inspect element" but is isn't visible. This was working fine in Chrome 45 and current version of FF along with IE 11.

Comment: Can you please put your issue in some fiddle , I can check there & fix it if possible .

Comment: Its working on my end. Need to see your code please.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Were you able to find a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by setting `frame: false` on the grid.

Comment: I fixed it the same way! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

frame: false works well, but deleting "overflow:hidden" from
.x-box-layout-ct {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative
}
worked for me.